# Error "OUT paramater used in non-stored procedure call : ORACLE_REF_CURSOR class java.sql.ResultSet" while running a Jasper Report

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jasper-reports

I am getting the following error when running the report. Any idea why? This is a report which was working earlier but not sure what changed and it stopped working.

> Error filling print... OUT paramater used in non-stored procedure call : ORACLE_REF_CURSOR class java.sql.ResultSet
>   Setting up the file resolver... 
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: OUT paramater used in non-stored procedure call : ORACLE_REF_CURSOR class java.sql.ResultSet 
>       at com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuter.createStatement(PlSqlQueryExecuter.java:369) 
>       at com.jaspersoft.jrx.query.PlSqlQueryExecuter.createDatasource(PlSqlQueryExecuter.java:113) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1086) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:667) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745) 
>       at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891) 
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
>   Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by removing the `ORACLE_REF_CURSOR` argument from procedure call within the Jasper report.

The procedure call was like `{call procedure1($P{param1}, $P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR})}` when it was throwing the above error. After removing the `ORACLE_REF_CURSOR` argument from the call, its working now. Here is how the procedure call looks like`{call procedure1($P{param1})}` in the report.

Funny thing is that the report was working before with the `ORACLE_REF_CURSOR` in the argument of the procedure, but suddenly started throwing the above error.

If somebody has more explanation on this problem then do please update the answer.

Comment: Have you came up with a solution how to use ORACLE_REF_CURSOR in Jasper Studio?